# How i can find non Nan occurrencies patterns in a multi index dataframe?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I am dealing with a multi-indexed dataframe that looks like this:

[image: multi indexed data frame]

(sorry for writing null instead of NaN)

What could be the most efficient way to find occurrences of the patterns i highlighted?

I expect to reach a result like this one:

[image: pattern occurrences i am looking for]

Thanks in advance for any insight!

For who wants to play with it:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd


df1_text = """       A  B C
STAND1 CH1 NaN NaN NaN
STAND1 CH2 NaN 11.2 NaN
STAND1 CH3 12.4 7.0 NaN
STAND1 CH4 10.2 2.0 NaN
STAND2 CH1 NaN 2.5 NaN
STAND2 CH2 NaN 11.2 NaN
STAND2 CH3 NaN NaN 6.3
STAND2 CH4 NaN NaN 23.5
STAND3 CH1 NaN NaN NaN
STAND3 CH2 12.3 NaN NaN
STAND3 CH3 5.3 4.5 NaN
STAND3 CH4 7.2 25.6 NaN"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df1_text), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: Do not post dataframes as images, post them as text.  That way they are easy to recreate and use.

Comment: Ok! i'll try. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Even better if you have a simple code snippet that can be used to create the dataframes!

Comment: Done! :) really thanks for the advice. It has been simpler than expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach. In short, you can use

```
df2 = df.swaplevel(0,1).unstack().notnull()
print(pd.Series(np.dot(df2.index, df2)).value_counts())
```

The first line creates `df2` that lines up the channel column with 9 columns of boolean indicators of cells that are not null, e.g.

```
         # A                    B                    C
    # STAND1 STAND2 STAND3 STAND1 STAND2 STAND3 STAND1 STAND2 STAND3
# CH1  False  False  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
# CH2  False  False   True   True   True  False  False  False  False
# CH3   True  False   True   True  False   True  False   True  False
# CH4   True  False   True   True  False   True  False   True  False
```

The goal of the second step is to replace each column in `df2` with a string representing an event. Using  the fact that Python strings can be multiplied by integers, we get

```
np.dot([CH1, CH2, CH3, CH4], [True, True, False, False])      <==>
'CH1' * True + 'CH2' * True + 'CH3' * False + 'CH4' * False   <==>
'CH1' * 1 + 'CH2' * 1 + 'CH3' * 0 + 'CH4' * 0                 <==>
'CH1' + 'CH2'                                                 <==>
'CH1CH2'
```

This has a cosmetic defect of omitting commas and including an "empty" event.

Full example:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd


df1_text = """       A  B C
STAND1 CH1 NaN NaN NaN
STAND1 CH2 NaN 11.2 NaN
STAND1 CH3 12.4 7.0 NaN
STAND1 CH4 10.2 2.0 NaN
STAND2 CH1 NaN 2.5 NaN
STAND2 CH2 NaN 11.2 NaN
STAND2 CH3 NaN NaN 6.3
STAND2 CH4 NaN NaN 23.5
STAND3 CH1 NaN NaN NaN
STAND3 CH2 12.3 NaN NaN
STAND3 CH3 5.3 4.5 NaN
STAND3 CH4 7.2 25.6 NaN"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df1_text), delim_whitespace=True)

# solution
df2 = df.swaplevel(0,1).unstack().notnull()
print(pd.Series(np.dot(df2.index, df2)).value_counts())

# In [559]: df.swaplevel(0,1).unstack().notnull()
# Out[559]:
         # A                    B                    C
    # STAND1 STAND2 STAND3 STAND1 STAND2 STAND3 STAND1 STAND2 STAND3
# CH1  False  False  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
# CH2  False  False   True   True   True  False  False  False  False
# CH3   True  False   True   True  False   True  False   True  False
# CH4   True  False   True   True  False   True  False   True  False

# In [560]: np.dot(df2.index, df2)
# Out[560]: 
# array(['CH3CH4', '', 'CH2CH3CH4', 'CH2CH3CH4', 'CH1CH2', 'CH3CH4', '',
       # 'CH3CH4', ''], dtype=object)

# In [561]: pd.Series(np.dot(df2.index, df2)).value_counts()
# Out[561]: 
# CH3CH4       3
             # 3
# CH2CH3CH4    2
# CH1CH2       1
# dtype: int64
```

Comment: this is great! just two rows! genial!